Fusion-like timeline in Python
In Autodesk Fusion, the timeline shows individual operations on a 3D model:

Each operation can be added, removed or modified at any point, with the 3D model being updated accordingly.
Under the hood, modifying an operation might work as follows:
for i in range(modified_operation_index, n):
    cache[i] = apply_operation(operation=operations[i],
                               initial_state=cache[operation - 1])

display(cache[n - 1])

The implication of this is that changes to operations do not require Fusion to run through all operations, but rather only the operations starting from the modified one.
I would like to have the same functionality in Build123d, which is a Python CAD library.
# %% Operation 1
from build123d import *
# ... more time-consuming imports ...

# %% Operation 2
box = Box(1, 2, 3)

# %% Operation 3
# ... more code that modifies box ...

# %% Operation 4
circle = Circle(4, 5)

# %% Operation 5
# ... more code that modifies circle ...

# %% Operation ...

# %% Operation n - 1
result = box + circle + ...

# %% Operation n
# show result in viewer

I don't want to wait for operations 1 through 16 to finish executing each time I want to preview a change to operation 17's code.
Is there a way to accomplish this in Python, possibly using external software such as IPython?

Yes, this is easily do-able and you were already on the right track. Using build123d with the OCP CAD Viewer extension in VSCode along with the Jupyter VSCode extension enables exactly the behavior you are after. Simply open an editor and add the IPython cell delimiters that you already used above (# %%). You can either click "Run Cell" or use the default keybinding of CTRL-Enter (probably CMD- on MacOS).
Example code:
# %% run imports once
from build123d import *
from ocp_vscode import *

# %% Operation 1
box = Box(1, 2, 3)

# %% Operation 2
cylinder = Cylinder(.4, 5)

# %% Operation 3
result = box + cylinder 

show_all() # actually view the object(s) in the 3D viewer

What running the cells actually does is send them to the Jupyter extension's "interactive window" which is similar to a jupyter-lab prompt or a REPL. When you execute the cells e.g. sequentially the namespace of the python interpreter is stateful (until the interactive window's kernel is restarted). I typically also keep the "show" statements at the end of the script and add cells as necessary.

The problem with "Run Cell" is that it operates on the current state of the program, whatever that may be, not the state at the end of the previous cell. This means that running the same cell multiple times will often exhibit the wrong behavior. Think of what happens when a cell contains box = box + extrude(top_face(box), 3) or some_generator() and is run multiple times in the development process.

@glibg10b I personally would avoid modifying box self referentially in separate cells. Also, I prefer to use the builder API rather than the algebra API because the indented "scope" marks the beginning and end of when that object can be modified (and it also provides a visual reference similar to a feature tree). I think that working on a portion of the design until it is "done" and then combining all the complete pieces at the end makes the most practical sense. CAD is complicated and not all tools or workflows are (or can be made to be) perfectly analogous.
